# Induction and Statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm having trouble with induction in my discrete math course.

We are given a statement we know (∀k)(P(k)⇒P(k+2)), where k is an element of N.

After that we have a series of statements, I'll give one for example, that we must say is true, false, or possibly true.

1. ∀n, P(n), where n is and element of N.

I don't even know where to begin with that statement.
Also, I know how induction works, but when I just see the implication, it doesn't help me out.

Thank you for reading this, I hope someone can point me in the right direction to solving these.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't even know where to begin with that statement. Also, I know how induction works, but when I just see the implication, it doesn't help me out.

**Exactly.**   You don't have enough information from the iteration step *alone* to either verify or falsify the statement.   You are missing the required base step.

That's your answer.   *It's possibly true*; iff $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ also holds then $\big\langle\forall n\in \Bbb N: P(n)\big\rangle$.

---

$$\overbrace{\;\\[2ex]\underbrace{\big\langle\forall n\in \Bbb N: \big(P(n)\to P(n+2)\big)\big\rangle}_\text{this is what you have} \wedge \underbrace{ P(0)\wedge P(1)\quad}_{\text{but you also need this}} \vdash \underbrace{\big\langle\forall n\in \Bbb N: P(n)\big\rangle}_{\text{in order to show this}}}^\text{Induction} $$

Comment: Wow, thank you for the info. That helps me a lot. I thought you'd need two base cases. I'm trying to wrap my head around needing two base cases, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @JerryBaldwin It is two base cases --one for odd natural numbers, and one for the evens-- because your iterative step increments by $2$.

Comment: I totally get it now. Thanks!

Comment: From our implication, could we conclude anything about ∀n P(n+2). I'm having trouble with this one.

Comment: @JerryBaldwin For an implication to be true, either the consequent is true or the antecedent is false.$\;$  If all we know about the antecedent is that it is is either true or false, then we can only conclude the same about the consequent (that $\;P(n+2)\;$ is either true or false).

Answer (score 0):

Induction says that if you know $\forall k, P(k) \implies P(k+1)$ *and* $P(0)$, then $P(n) \forall n$. So if you only have the first half of the conditions, then the conclusion holds if and only if $P(0)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to readjust the information on the second line to P(k+2). Does that mean for 1. to be true I have have to prove P(0) and p(1) to be true? I just saw the definition you said in a book I was reading.

Comment: @JerryBaldwin Yes.